# Font file flagged as malicious by antivirus

Tags: malware, antivirus, font

BitDefender (Free edition) for Windows identified the `CascadiaCode.ttf` font file as malware and moved it from the Fonts folder into quarantine.

My Windows 11 install is like a day old, so maybe it's less likely(?) it's infected. I Googled for anyone else with the same experience but I couldn't find anything.

What are the possible reasons it was identified as malware?

Comment: We can't tell you why an AV product would have flagged a file knowing only that it flagged a file. Try submitting the file to VirusTotal.com

Comment: It's strange because when I went to the path where the file was (C:\Windows\Fonts\Cascadia.ttf) I didn't see it with the other fonts. So I tried downloading it (https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/download/cascadia-code) and installing it - but I get a message claiming it's already installed. I tried submitting the font file from FontSquirrel.com to VirusTotal and it reported that the file is clean according to all AVs.

Comment: that is odd... sometimes font managers will store fonts in their own location methinks... and not sure about web fonts (location of those?  local browser/user folder?)